# How to check array of arrays of strings for difference

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check an array of arrays of strings to check if they have different values. The main array may include several arrays, from 1 to many. The inner arrays of strings may also include from 1 property to many (order of properties is not guaranteed). Here's the desired result:

```js
[['foo']] //false
[['foo'], ['foo']] //false
[['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo', 'bar']] //true
[['bar'], ['foo'], ['bar']] // true
[['foo'], ['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'bar']] //true
[['foo', 'baz'], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['bar', 'foo']] //true
```

I tried lodash `_.difference`, but that didn't work (perhaps I didn't use it correctly). Thought about flattening the array with `Array.flat()`, but not sure what to do next.

Any suggestion how to do it, please?

Comment: Is the result of `[['foo'], ['foo', 'foo']]` true or false? what about `[['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'bar']]`?

Comment: Make a flatten copy of the array, and a Set of the copy, then compare the length of the flatten array and set.

Comment: What is `[['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'bar']]` expected to evaluate to?

Comment: @Nick Basically the strings in the inner arrays always will be different. They're sort of IDs. In the second case it should resolve to false.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It should resolve to false.

Comment: That's important, because in your question it's unclear whether you want multiple distinct values or multiple distinct sub-arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flat the array, get the array of unique values, and check the length of that array

Below solution uses lodash

```
const check = (arrayOfArray) =>
  _.chain(arrayOfArray).flatten().uniq().value().length !== 1
```

```js
const check = (arrayOfArray) =>
  _.chain(arrayOfArray).flatten().uniq().value().length !== 1

console.log(check([["foo"]]))
console.log(check([["foo"], ["foo"]]))
console.log(check([["foo"], ["foo"], ["foo", "bar"]]))
console.log(check([["bar"], ["foo"], ["bar"]]))
console.log(check([["foo"], ["foo", "bar"], ["foo", "bar"]]))
console.log( check([ ["foo", "baz"], ["foo", "bar", "baz"], ["bar", "foo"], ]) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, really didn't expect for basically an one line solution! Very elegant! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just one more thing: with array `[['foo', 'bar']]` I got `true`, when expected result was `false`. So I just altered your solution a bit and added `&& arrayOfArray.length > 1` at the end. Now worked just great!

Comment: Well, just like I was asked in the comments, `[['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'bar']]` was resolved to `true`, but should be resolved to `false`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Igal you could map and join the value, and the rest do the same `_.chain(arrayOfArray).map((array) => _.join(array, "-")).uniq().value().length !== 1`

Answer (score 1):

Think about if there is an array of string you have to find if there is difference, that would be easy by using:

```
_.unique(myArray).length === 1 ? true : false;
```

But you have an array of array. So you can make the nested array as one string.
That will make your problem similar to the easier one.

For example:

```
oneDimentionalArray = myArray.map( el => el.join('$'));
// The $ is for seperate two array ['aa', 'b'] and ['a', 'ab']. 
// Because after joining them that will make similar string without any separator.
_.unique(oneDimentionalArray).length === 1 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses ES6 with no dependencies:

```
const array = [['foo', 'baz'], ['foo', 'baz'], ['foo', 'baz']];
const reducedArray = array.reduce((all, current) => `${all}${current}`)
const isDifferent = reducedArray !== `${array[0]}`.repeat(array.length)
```

The `array` variable will contain the array you are checking.

The `isSame` variable will be true if the array contains different values.

Comment: If you look closely, I am not comparing arrays I am actually comparing string values of the arrays.